# Get embed id in frame with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that I load with a SCORM file. The SCORM file loads a lot of things, but the only thing I need to get is the id of the embed element in order to change it's height. I tried to change height with the `.css()` method, but it didn't work. The following is an image of the source with the target element highlighted.

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2P3b.png)

I tried this so far:

```
$('.scorm').contents().find('#scorm_iframe').contents().find('frameset').find('frame').get(0).contentWindow.document.all[16];
```

But i only get `div id="divSwf"`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post relevant html in the question

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't just cut and paste the code into a snippet* or a [fiddle](https://sjfiddle.net)? *7th icon on comment toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other methods that can be used instead of [`innerHeight`](https://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/). You can use [`height`](https://api.jquery.com/height/) or [`outerHeight`](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight;/) as well. Keep in mind the results very according to what your'e using and with what.

```js
$(function() {
  var H = 500;
  $('#scorm_content').load(function() {
    $('#scorm_content').contents().find("#eplayer").innerHeight(H);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="scorm_content" src="/"></iframe>

<!-- This is Pseudo code of the page within the iframe
<table...
          <tbody...
                <tr...
                       <td...
                           <div....
                                    <object...
                                          <embed id="eplayer" .... -->
```